# How can I resize a 2D vector of objects given the width and height?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, resize, multidimensional-array

My class, `GameBoard`, has a member variable that is a 2D vector of an object of the class `Tile`. The `GameBoard` constructor takes width and height as parameters.

How can I get the 2D vector of `Tile` objects to resize according to the width and height passed to the constructor?  How can I fill it with `Tile` objects so that I can do something like this?

```
myVector[i][j].getDisplayChar();
```

**Snippet**

```
m_vvTiles.resize(iHeight);

for(auto it = m_vvTiles.begin(); it != m_vvTiles.end(); it++ ){

    (*it).resize(iWidth,Tile(' '));
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<>` is not multidimensional.  Which vector class are you using?

Comment: std::vector<std::vector<Tile>> m_vvTiles; It works like that with char type

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to resize the outer and inner vectors separately.

```
myVector.resize(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    myVector[i].resize(m);
```

Comment: Ok so n is width and m is height? And then could I just do a double for loop and push objects into the vector?

Comment: @Justin I didn't want to assume which was which width vs. height since that's entirely up to you and the assumptions you've made in your program. If you'd rather push than resize that's fine, but you have to make sure to push the right number of elements - it will be larger on the new outer ones.

Comment: Ah ok. So instead of pushing Tile objects, I could fill it when doing the resize?

Comment: @Justin, yes you can put a default value on the `resize` call.

Comment: Could it work with the snippet I just added? Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Justin, the snippet looks fine. I'd use `it->resize` instead of `(*it).resize` though.

Comment: Can use optional argument `resize(n, value)` where to set each new element with initial value of `value`

Answer (score 61):

You don't need to create external loop to resize a 2 dimensional vector (matrix). You can simply do the following one line `resize()` call:

```
//vector<vector<int>> M;
//int m = number of rows, n = number of columns;
M.resize(m, vector<int>(n));
```

Comment: I know this post is old, but I do want to clarify that the standard notation for a matrix is MxN, where M is the number of rows and N is the number of columns.

Comment: just wonder, comparing with accepted answer, will it unnecessarily construct vector and copy it m times?

Comment: How does this resize the already existing rows?  Looks like a big bug waiting to happen.

Comment: This method only resizes one dimension for me. Caused a bug in my code that took me a while to find, as the comment above suggests.

Comment: Attention: Although this answer is on the top, it is just wrong as stated above.

Comment: @ThelVadam I am still breaking my head over what is wrong with this solution. As far as I can see this resizes vector M with m elements. Each element is a vector of size n. So I end up with m x n elements. I do understand this might be a special case of resizing which only initializes. It cannot be use to expand a vector already containing data.

Comment: @JohannesLinkels If the size ist increasing, only the new elements are assigned the vector with the new size n like Mark said. Hence If we have a 5x5 vector and we resize it like above to a 10x10 vector we geht 5 rows with a vector of size 5 with the following 5 rows having a vector with 10 elements.

Comment: @ThelVadam That is correct what you say. Now I see.

Answer (score 15):

We can also use single line code:

```
matrix.resize( row_count , vector<int>( column_count , initialization_value ) );
```

If code is repeatedly changing the dimensions and matrix is sometimes shrinking also then before re-sizing clear the old state of matrix(2D vector)

```
matrix.clear();
matrix.resize( row_count , vector<int>( column_count , initialization_value ) );

// we can create a 2D integer vector with 3 rows and 5 columns having "-1" as initial value by:
matrix.clear();
matrix.resize(3, vector<int> (5,-1));
```

Answer (score 1):

best practice would be to use

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix;  //creating 2d vector
int r,c;                     
cin>>r>>c;                    //taking input from user 
matrix.resize(r, vector<int>(c));   //resizing 2d vector according to required space only
```