# How can I resize a 2D C++ vector?

Tags: c++, vector, resize

I have a 2D `char` vector:

```
vector< vector<char> > matrix;
```

I will read in a matrix as an input and store it in that vector. The size of my vector is fixed and is ROW x COL. I guess I need to resize it for each row and column.

How can I accomplish it without taking extra memory (resizing it correctly)?

Comment: What is the problem with calling `resize`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resize a 2D vector of objects given the width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889578/how-can-i-resize-a-2d-vector-of-objects-given-the-width-and-height)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Given the vector is empty**, you can simply resize the outer vector with preallocated inner vectors without the need of a loop:

```
matrix.resize(ROW, vector<char>(COL));
```

Alternatively, when **initializing** or if you want to reset a **non-empty vector**, you can use the constructor overload taking a size and initial value to initialize all the inner vectors:

```
matrix = vector<vector<char> >(ROW, vector<char>(COL));
```

I assumed you access it with `matrix[row][col]`. In C++ matrices are usually stored in row-major order. If you wanted column-major order, you need to swap the arguments `ROW` and `COL`.

Comment: Do you mean for the first line code you wrote or the second one? Because I'll access it with    `matrix[row][col]`

Comment: Swapping the arguments? It's meant for both. Both lines initialize the outer vector with freshly constructed instances of the inner vector; all being correctly resized initially. You initialize the outer vector with zeroed column/row vectors, so to say.

Comment: I noticed that if the columns were larger than rows the correct code should be  `matrix.resize(row, vector<char>(col));` Otherwise it would give some memory allocation problems

Comment: Do you mean for mine or for @leemes' ?

Comment: The problem with this code is that it dies not resize inner vectors. It only resizes the outer vector.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow But it initializes the inner vectors by filling them with an initial number of elements; see the vector constructor taking an int.

Comment: Multiple resizes will fail with the above solution. It will only work for this particular situation in the problem. The second argument in the resize() method is used to initialize only the extra elements but not all the elements in the outer container

Comment: @krishna222 Please read the beginning of my first sentence (of the answer) again: **Given the vector is empty**. Note that I give an alternative for the general case.

Comment: @leemes, can you make it bold then, because its misleading for most of us, who just immediately skip to the code part sometimes.

Comment: @krishna222 I edited the answer, I hope it is clearer now. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

```
    const size_t ROW = 10;
    const size_t COL = 20;
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> v;

    v.resize( ROW );

    std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), 
                   std::bind2nd( std::mem_fun_ref( &std::vector<char>::resize ), COL ) );

    std::cout << "size = " << v.size() << std::endl;
    for ( const std::vector<char> &v1 : v ) std::cout << v1.size() << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: Why this complicated? `v.resize` takes the initial content as the second parameter.

Comment: Also, [`mem_fun_ref` is deprecated](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun_ref).

Answer (score 0):

While construction with sized vector as default value, given by @leemes, is quite an answer, there is an alternative without using an additional vector and copy ctor:

```
assert(COL >= 0);
assert(ROW >= 0);
vector<vector<char>> matrix;
for (size_t i{0}; i != COL; ++i)
{
    matrix.emplace_back(ROW);
}
```