# no match for 'operator=' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, vector

I am new to c++. I am trying to make 2 D dynamic array(vector) of pointers that points to a 2 D dynamic array that contains characters. I need to understand the logic as I want to implement it on my assigned project. I have a very weak foundation in pointers.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyetu.png)

```
#include<vector>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> *  pointer;
int matX = 2;
int matY = 2;



void mkPMat(vector<vector<int>> &);
void update();




int main(){

    vector<vector<int>> arr;
    int a;

    for(int i =0; i<matX; i++){
        vector<int> temp;
        for(int j =0; j<matY; j++){
            cout<<"Enter the charactyer"<<endl;
            cin>>a;
            temp.push_back(a);
        }
        arr.push_back(temp);
    }
    mkPMat(arr);

}


void mkPMat(vector<vector<int>>& arry){

    for(int i =0; i<matX; i++){
        vector<int*> tp;
        for(int j =0; j<matY; j++){
            tp.push_back(&arry[i][j]);
        }
        pointer.push_back(tp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not your problem, but you'll run into it soon anyway, `vector<vector<int>> arr;` in itself doesn't allocate any memory. Thus, `cin>>arr[i][j]` will crash your program once it compiles.

Comment: So how do I resolve it?  I just ran my code and it crashed as you have mentioned. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're going to need [`resize()` or `reserve()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029299/stdvectorresize-vs-stdvectorreserve) to do that. Probably `resize()`, I think.

Comment: BTW: both `arry` and `pointer` will need to be resized.

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15889578/10957435) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20047684/10957435) for applying this to 2d vectors.

Comment: Sorry for such a dumb question. I see that I forgot to do the push back too.

Comment: Hi, can anyone help with the question below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60782007/updating-a-matrix-dynamic-2-d-array-my-program-compiles-but-the-desired-output.   Thnank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that `vector<vector<int>> *  pointer;` is a pointer to a vector of vectors. That's different from what you put on this line:

```
pointer[i][j] = &arry[i][j];
```

Here you're setting a position in your vector to a pointer to an int. That is, `&arry[i][j]` is an `int *`. `pointer`, on the other hand, is a `std::vector<std::vector<int *>>`. The compiler doesn't know what to do to convert these two to each other.

What you actually seem to want is for `pointer` to be an `std::vector<std::vector<int *>>`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int *>> pointer;
```

Comment: Hi, can you help with the question below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60782007/updating-a-matrix-dynamic-2-d-array-my-program-compiles-but-the-desired-output.   Thnank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a 2D array of pointers like here

```
pointer[i][j] = &arry[i][j];
```

then this needs the signature

```
vector<vector<int*>> pointer;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, can you help with the question below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60782007/updating-a-matrix-dynamic-2-d-array-my-program-compiles-but-the-desired-output.   Thnank you