# Is there a quick way I can make a vector of vector using just one type of element?

Tags: c++, vector

So I want to make a vector of vector that has 5 elements in each vector and 4 vectors in the first vector. And I want to make all the elements just False.

I could:

```
vector <vector<bool> > a;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    vector<bool> tmp;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        tmp.push_back(False);
    a.push_back(tmp);
```

But is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: Use the constructor `vector<vector<bool>> a(4, vector<bool>(5, false))`

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<bool>> a(4, std::vector<bool>(5))` should create `a` with the correct sized and values to begin with. It uses the third variant of the constructors [listed here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resize a 2D vector of objects given the width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889578/how-can-i-resize-a-2d-vector-of-objects-given-the-width-and-height)

Comment: Please note that having a vector of bools [might not be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794569/why-is-vectorbool-not-a-stl-container) a good idea.

Comment: Normally [I use this alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301) when I need a rectangular 2D, but in the case of `vector<bool>` it makes a great example of @Ron 's point. `vector<bool>` is so different that it even gets [its own documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the constructor

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> a(4, std::vector<bool>(5, false));
}
```

With C++17 you don't even need the types ([wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HX164ZkoRJDLyedw)):

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector a(4, std::vector(5, false));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, very simple:

```
vector <vector<bool> > a( 4, vector<bool>(5, false) );
```