# Getting subscript out of range after vector resize

Tags: c++

I have a 2D vector of string. It has some data in it already - generally speaking all rows (should) have the same number of columns.

I am looking to resize the matrix by increasing the number of columns by 1.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> completeMatrix;
matrixRowNum = completeMatrix.size();
matrixColumnNum = completeMatrix[0].size();
completeMatrix.resize(matrixRowNum, std::vector<std::string>(matrixColumnNum + 1)); //My attempt to resize by 1. Same result if I try 20.
completeMatrix[0][matrixColumnNum] = "inputString"; //getting subscript out of range error here.

completeMatrix[0][matrixColumnNum-1] = "inputString"; //however this works fine. it's like I never called resize.
```

What am I missing?
(*if there's a better way to do this than vectors, I'll take any recommendations along those lines as well*).

(if helpful, I am on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2019).

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Hint: resize does not prepend the desired value.

Comment: What value do you think `matrixRowNum` contains?

Comment: ```matrixRowNum``` contains the value that I expected to see (in my particular case its 198).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `resize` call only affects new rows.  All existing rows are unaffected.

But you're not even adding rows!  You called `resize` and passed the same value as the current size.  So nothing will happen.  It seems you have a misunderstanding of how much magic and mind-reading happens inside this call.

You will need to iterate through your rows and resize each one.  Here is one way you could do it:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> StringMatrix;

void AddColumns(StringMatrix& m, size_t count = 1, const std::string& val = "inputString")
{
    if (m.empty() || count < 1)
        return;
    size_t cols = m.front().size() + count;
    for (auto& row : m)
        row.resize(cols, val);
}
```

Comment: I've used resize elsewhere successfully as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44270940/5556320). The only difference is that I've only used it soon after initialization, not with a prepopulated vector.

Comment: Yeah, and that's quite a big difference, isn't it...

Comment: Is that behavior documented somewhere? (not arguing, just curious).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize .. Pay attention to the fact that "new values" get the default.  Existing values remain unchanged.  Thank goodness for that!

Comment: Thank you! I think I got it. When I was using the resize with two arguments, I was picturing in my head that I am telling the vector to magically increase rows, and columns. What it was actually doing was creating "new" 1d vectors and "assigning" those as value to the vector in the other dimension. Since there are "existing values", the short hand doesn't work.

Comment: Best not to think of it as "other dimension".  A vector is one-dimensional.  End of story.  A vector of vectors is just that -- a whole bunch of vectors.  It is not a "2D vector".  There is nothing special about the contents of the vector values it contains.  The only thing that makes it seem 2D is the rule you imposed yourself on the program whereby you're making all those vectors the same size.  In reality there is no such limitation.